# Raw json return from SFDX

Tags: salesforcedx

Using the `--json` switch with an SFDX command returns JSON to stdout. However, if I consume a command in a node process, e.g.

`child_process.execFileSync('sfdx', ['force:limits:api:display', '-u', 'alias', '--json']).toString();`

It does return the JSON, but due to the CLI formatting if the JSON (i.e. the colours) we get all the ANSI escape codes too (so instead of e.g. `{ }` we get `\u001b[97m{ \u001b[97m}`) making it more effort to parse. Is there a way to get raw JSON back instead of formatted?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this as well until I came across some regex from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245716/remove-all-ansi-colors-styles-from-strings/29497680), which solved the problem for me.

Give this a try:

```
let resp = child_process.execFileSync('sfdx', ['force:limits:api:display', '-u', 'alias', '--json']).toString();
let sanitizedResp = resp.replace(/[\u001b\u009b][[()#;?]*(?:[0-9]{1,4}(?:;[0-9]{0,4})*)?[0-9A-ORZcf-nqry=><]/g, '');
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Yes, thats the solution i went with 

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me (unless I misunderstood something in your question) -

```
JSON.parse(child_process.execFileSync('sfdx', ['force:limits:api:display', '-u', 'alias', '--json']).toString())
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, I think because you are running from the node cli, the ansi colour codes are being converted for the benefit of your view. If you did the same from within code and then inspect the response you'd see those ansi colour codes.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you for clarifying that.